# What subsequent patents reference this patent?

Tags: usa

In reference to the patent: [US7713314](https://www.google.com/patents/US7713314)

Answer (score 1):

Currently No patent cite this patent as reference. below is quick method to check forward citations:-

[image]

Comment: Give this guy a cookie, he made a gif just to show this :O +100000

Comment: Will an up vote do?  I have to figure out haw to do this.